# Application is loading but no content is displaying in Super Dev Mode

Tags: gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode

I migrated my GWT `classic dev mode` to `super dev mode` and configured every think in GWT 2.5.1 rc.While launching its compiling the application but when i hit the `hostpage(html)` its not loading the content.Apart from this is there any think i need to configure ?

Comment: Why don't you use GWT 2.7.0? This version handles SDM much better?

Comment: Not helping but SDM is pretty hard to use and configure even with 2.7.0. Good luck with 2.5.1.

Comment: Can't agree. SDM in GWT 2.7.0 is quit easy to use. Hope this helps: https://docs.sencha.com/gxt/3.1/getting_started/sdm/SuperDevMode.html

Comment: Right now i cant use GWT 2.7 ...My apps is very big..it will some more time to migrate..I need to use GWt 2.5.1 ly...